# The most elegant way to require parent::__construct()

Tags: php, oop

Say I have the following controller structure:

```
class Controller {

    public function __construct(){
       $this->accessControl();
    }
}

class Account extends Controller {

   public function __construct(User $user){

      parent::__construct();
      $this->user = $user;
   }
}
```

How to require other devs to explicitly call `parent::__construct()` in their child controllers? It contains critical stuff like access control etc

So far I decided to wrap all functions from parent constructor into `init()` method which sets `initialized` property to TRUE, then check this property in the router. If it's not TRUE - throw an exceptions.

```
public $initialized = false;

class Controller {

    public function __construct(){
       $this->init();
    }
}

protected function init(){
   $this->accessControl();
   $this->initialized = true;
}

class Router {
    public function process($path){
       $controller = new User();
       if(!$controller instanceof Controller || !$controller->initialized){
          throw new Exception('Error');
       }
    }
}
```

Does it smell bad?

Comment: `parent::__construct()` seems elegant. Since the child class is dependant on it, not calling it would mean they cannot access variables created in the `__construct()` function of the parent class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same is needed in [Symfony\Console](https://github.com/symfony/console) Command, where **constructor has to add command name and definition**.

[They handle it like this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/87adf25091568810e0d2996b17f9db25d9ee8147/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php#L447) in single place where the command is added. So your approach to check controller in Router is the same. **I'd got for it**, rather then put the responsibility to abstract Controller or some reflection.

---

On the other hand, it looks `accessControl()` should be checked on **security layer level** and not in router.

**What framework do you use?**

Could you decouple it from router by using EventSubscriber and framework event?

Comment: It's not a framework, writing my own :). "Could you decouple it from router by using EventSubscriber and framework event?" It's already decoupled. Two different classes for different purposes. The router just look at list of predefined routes (regexp patterns) and calls an appropriate controller method

Comment: "accessControl() should be checked on security layer level" What do you mean? Controller is responsible for access control, isn't it?

Comment: But that approach can have it's pitfalls when combined with non-standard approach: see issue from this week on Symfony Command: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/26203

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it smells bad.

> How to require other devs to explicitly call parent::__construct() in
>   their child controllers?

Well, firstly, you should trust your developers. The other question would be how can one be sure that all controllers have access control. To assure this you have to cover all your controllers with tests. So for each controller should be tested, that checks whether an unauthorized user can access it.

> So far I decided to wrap all functions from parent constructor into
>   `init()` method which sets `initialized` property to TRUE, then check this
>   property in the router.

Actually, your `init` function has no value, as you just moved code from `__construct` (and at the end of the day now you have to ensure your developers call `init` function -- see, only the name is changed;)). You can as well set `initialized` in `__construct` itself.

> ```
> if(!$controller instanceof Controller || !$controller->initialized){
>     throw new Exception('Error');
> }
> ```

So you will end up enforcing your developers to check whether or not the controller was initialized, in every place, it will be used in.

I guess you cannot make code foolproof. You have to trust developers to do the right thing and educate new team members. And of course, you should cover all your code with tests because in practice this is the only thing that ensures developers that they did the right thing.

There is a good podcast, that is tangible to your question: ["Type Safety Roundtable with Ryan Tablada and Matt Machuga"](http://www.fullstackradio.com/10).

Comment: Some time ago I completely stopped using class inheritance. So should you.

Comment: @Mike, so I assume you do not use any major frameworks. Otherwise, it is really hard to do, as frameworks dictate you to use inheritance.

Comment: @Mike, to be honest, I agree with you, that it is better to use composition over inheritance, and declare classes final by default. But as we don't live in Wonderland, it can be pretty tough to achieve.

Comment: It’s tough but it’s worth it. Classes are easier to maintain and test. I use Symfony by the way. It does not force me to anything.